# Cumulative count distinct in Netezza

Tags: sql, distinct, netezza, windowing

I'm using Netezza.  I'm working with marketing data, specifically coupons.  Right now I'm counting distinct daily coupon redeemers; no big deal.  I'd like to get the count of distinct redeemers to date, though.  Note that it's not just the sum of daily redeemers, since a customer might redeem on different days, and therefore the sum of daily redeemers could be multi-counting customers.

I closed my eyes, made a wish, and executed the following query hoping it would work:

```
select redemption_date
      ,count(distinct(customer_id)) as day_redeemers
      ,count(distinct(customer_id)) over (partition by null rows unbounded preceding) as cml_redeemers
from coupon_history
group by 1
order by 1
```

But Netezza complains:
    ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Attribute CUSTOMER_ID must be GROUPed or used in an aggregate function

...and so I close my eyes, make a wish, and execute the following (note the addition to the group by):

```
select redemption_date
      ,count(distinct(customer_id)) as day_redeemers
      ,count(distinct(customer_id)) over (partition by null rows unbounded preceding) as cml_redeemers
from coupon_history
group by 1,customer_id
order by 1
```

Netezza complains as follows:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  DISTINCT aggregate not allowed in window with ORDER BY or frame specification
```

That error leads me to think that internally Netezza is ordering the customer_id in order to count transitions and thus distincts.  But it does leave me at sort of a loss for what I should try next.  I was hoping for something simple, but apparently it's not my lucky day.

Any ideas on how to make my original query work, or suggestions on an alternate approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always resort to brute force -- that is, to a correlated subquery:

```
select redemption_date,
       count(distinct(customer_id)) as day_redeemers,
       (select count(distinct ch2.customer_id)
        from coupon_history ch2
        where ch2.redemption_date <= ch.redemption_date
       ) as cml_redeemers
from coupon_history ch
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Of course, performance will not be as good.

EDIT:

Another way to approach this is to get the first redemption date for each customer and then just use cumulative sums:

```
select minrd,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by minrd) as cml_redeemers
from (select ch.customer_id, min(redemption_date) as minrd
      from coupon_history ch
      group by ch.customer_id
     ) ch
group by minrd;
```

Comment: The second approach *must* be clever, because I'm having trouble understanding it.  But it looks like you're treating the customers first redemption date as sort of the ID of that customer... and since they can only have one min date, then we don't duplicate over the subsequent days. **I do think** that you mean sum(count(*)) over (order by minrd) ... otherwise you just get row numbers, basically.

Comment: @Chris . . . You have exactly the right idea on the second approach.  And, yes, that should be `sum(count(*))` (it is fixed now).

Comment: Cool.  That works fine!  As for the first approach, I always forget about correlated subqueries (especially as a single selected value)... I think it's a subconscious defense mechanism.  Nevertheless, I tried it out and apparently Netezza wants no part of it.  It complains, "This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting".  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Chris . . . It is odd that Netezza doesn't support the first version.  It is standard SQL *and* Postgres supports the syntax.  I'm surprised.

Comment: Well... maybe I broke it.  My query above was simplified to remove some wheres.  The query wouldn't paste well in this little box, but I have it at http:// www.wepaste.com/ hammondegger/ if you want to take a look (I put two spaces in there so that SO wouldn't break my link).

Comment: @Chris . . . Your query looks reasonable; it is probably a Netezza limitation.